# Dose any one know why post man is returning null values from fields that are not on my sql table?

Tags: asp.net, json, api, postman

So I'm pretty new to SQL and web API, but here goes...  I have 4 tables in my database, 3 tables have foreign keys feeding into the other.  I have been able display my data in postman.  Although postman is giving me additional data fields with "null" entries at the bottom.  These fields are not present in the table that I am fetching.  Although they are present in my other tables.  [image: here is the Json from postman]

here is how my data tables look

[image]

here is my Model - I think it may be because of these virtual classes in the model.  If so how can I stop them being displayed for this particular HTTP get request.

[image]

i'm not really too sure whats going on with this

Sorry about the MASSIVE images, don't no what thats about :D any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: What are you using to serialize? You will need something like `[JsonIgnore]` attribute on those four properties.

Comment: I have only have a .gitignore  file in my project.  How do I add [JsonIgnore] and further more how do I configure it to not show these fields?

Comment: Got it working.  Thank you very much @Charlieface.  :D

Comment: As an aside, if you're using your database entities as models for your front end you may wish to stop, and instead have classes that hold only the attributes/properties the front end needs and other classes (the db entities) for interacting with the db. AitoMapoer can take the headache out of translating a front end data transfer object into a db entity object and back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mark your properties with [JsonIgnore]:

```
[JsonIgnore]
public virtual TblModelName Name { get;...
```

To prevent it being serialized. I believe that this attribute works for both [NewtonSoft.Json](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/PropertyJsonIgnore.htm) and [System.Text.Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonignoreattribute?view=netcore-3.1)

Answer (score 0):

Try removing [] array paranthesis and simply put in {} curly brackets it will take values as you enter from postman via post request.